# Выравнивание по центру абсолютно спозицированного элемента

Tags: html, css, позиционирование, выравнивание

Мне нужно выровнять по центру в горизонте абсолютно спозиционированный элемент относительно своего относительно спозиционированного родителя. Чтобы не пустословить, прикреплю фрагмент кода.

```css
html {
 font-family: Zurich, Verdana, sans-serif;
 /*background-color: var(--color-site-background);
 color: var(--color-site-font);*/
}
html,
body {
 /*min-width: 1280px;*/
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
input {
 font-family: inherit;
}
body>header {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 0 0 100%;
 grid-template-rows: 100% 0 0;
 grid-template-areas:
  "l o o"
  "l s a"
  "l n n";
 cursor: default;
}
nav.top-menu>ul,
body>header ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
header .logo {
 grid-area: l;
}
header .search {
 grid-area: s;
}
header .options {
 grid-area: o;
 justify-self: end;
}
header .options>li>div {
 text-decoration: node;
}
header .options>li>div:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
header .options li>ul {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 width: max-content;
 background: #ababab;
}
header .options li:hover>ul {
 visibility: visible;
}
header .account {
 grid-area: a;
}
header .options>li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 width: fit-content;
 padding: 0 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
body>header>* {
 align-self: center;
 justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ru-RU">
  <head>
    <meta encoding="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <ul class="options">
        <li name="regime">
          <div>Цветовой режим</div>
          <ul>
            <li name="day">Дневной</li>
            <li name="night">Ночной</li>
            <li name="settins">настройки</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Как это можно сделать, ваши версии?

Comment: Извиняюсь за тавтологию

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду список выпаюащий под Цветовым режимом по центру..или сам весь список на центр страницы?

Comment: @FX_Sektor, Список, выпадающий под цветовым режимом по центру. Я просто для вопроса в grid-template... указал не те единицы, на самом проекте .options - это тоненькая полосочка в 18pt в самом верху страницы, где по идее, при наведении на li, должен выпадать этот список

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
    header .options li>ul{
        left:50%;
        transform:translateX(-50%);
    }
</style>
```